# Preventing wrapping in dynamically loaded OPTIONs

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have a portion of a form with a series of Questions/Answers, some of which are SELECT dropdowns. These are loaded with a single “dummy” OPTION, and the actual options are then loaded by an ajax call.

One of these is now causing some wrapping to occur. I have mocked up the situation in this codepen : http://codepen.io/esdictor/pen/wBKyzv

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="leftColumn">
  <ul>
    <li class="dataRow clearFix" data-questionid="1">
      <div class="dataQuestion">Question:</div>
      <div class="dataAnswer">
        <select class="dataDropDown">
          <option value="0">Select ...</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dataRow clearFix" data-questionid="2">
      <div class="dataQuestion">Hi there:</div>
      <div class="dataAnswer">
        <input class="dataText" type="text" />
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="LoadOptions();" />
```

**CSS**

```
.clearFix:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}

.leftColumn {
  background-color: #BAE6FF;
  width: 15em;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  overflow: auto;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 2em;
  clear: left;
}

.dataQuestion {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  min-width: 6em;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}

dataAnswer {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.dataDropDown {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.dataText {
 width: 5em; 
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function LoadOptions()
{
  var $newOption = $('<option value="1">This is a really long answer</option>');
  $('.dataRow[data-questionid="1"]').find('.dataAnswer select').append($newOption);
}
```

Clicking the “Click Me!” button will emulate the loading of a long item that causes the wrapping.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Evan

Comment: Simple: your `15em` container is not wide enough to contain the label and the select. Consider applying a `width` to the select element to force its size to fit.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Part of the problem is that everything is dynamic here. They can resize the .leftColumn div, and I have no way of knowing what will load into the OPTION elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed elsewhere you can use an overflow scroll on the `li` combined with `white-space:nowrap` to force inline elements not to break. Here I substituted a span for you `dataAnswer` div

```js
function LoadOptions() {
  var $newOption = $('<option value="1">This is a really long answer</option>');
  $('.dataRow[data-questionid="1"]').find('.dataAnswer select').append($newOption);
}
```

```css
.clearFix:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}
.leftColumn {
  background-color: #BAE6FF;
  width: 15em;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  overflow: auto;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 2em;
  clear: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.dataQuestion {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 4em;
  margin-left: 0.25em;
}
dataAnswer {} .dataDropDown {} .dataText {
  width: 5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="leftColumn">
  <ul>
    <li class="dataRow clearFix" data-questionid="1">
      <div class="dataQuestion">Question:</div>
      <span class="dataAnswer">
        <select class="dataDropDown">
          <option value="0">Select ...</option>
        </select>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li class="dataRow clearFix" data-questionid="2">
      <div class="dataQuestion">Hi there:</div>
      <span class="dataAnswer">
        <input class="dataText" type="text" />
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="LoadOptions();" />
```

Comment: Still having some issues getting it to work in my application, but I can't deny that it works in the snippet. Thanks!